Multicast UDP local transfer failed using Flute protocol in Rust
I'm trying to run the flute in rust demo code in my local.
I modified demo code from read me to below
use flute::sender::Sender;
use flute::sender::ObjectDesc;
use flute::sender::Cenc;
use flute::core::UDPEndpoint;
use std::net::UdpSocket;
use std::time::SystemTime;
use flute::receiver::{writer, MultiReceiver};
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration; 
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;  


fn main() {
    println!("Begin");
    let receiver_thread = thread::Builder::new()  
        .name("ReceiverThread".to_string())  
        .spawn(|| fn_set_receiver())  
        .expect("Failed to create receiver thread"); 
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));  
    let sender_thread = thread::Builder::new()  
        .name("SenderThread".to_string())  
        .spawn(|| fn_set_sender())  
        .expect("Failed to create sender thread"); 
    sender_thread.join().unwrap(); 
    receiver_thread.join().unwrap();  
    println!("End");
}

fn fn_set_sender() {
    println!("Begin sender");
        // Create UDP Socket
    let udp_socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:0").unwrap();
    udp_socket.connect("224.0.1.201:3400").expect("Connection failed");

    // Create FLUTE Sender
    let tsi = 1;
    let oti = Default::default();
    let config = Default::default();
    let endpoint = UDPEndpoint::new(None, "224.0.1.201".to_string(), 3400);
    let mut sender = Sender::new(endpoint, tsi, &oti, &config);

    // Add object(s) (files) to the FLUTE sender (priority queue 0)
    let obj = ObjectDesc::create_from_buffer(b"hello world", "text/plain",
    &url::Url::parse(r#"C:\Users\myname\Documents\_\Multicast\src\data.txt"#).unwrap(), 1, None, None, None, Cenc::Null, true, None, true).unwrap();
    sender.add_object(0, obj);

    // Always call publish after adding objects
    sender.publish(SystemTime::now());

    // Send FLUTE packets over UDP/IP
    while let Some(pkt) = sender.read(SystemTime::now()) {
        udp_socket.send(&pkt).unwrap();
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1));
    }
    println!("End sender");
}

fn fn_set_receiver() {
    println!("Begin Receiver");
    // Create UDP/IP socket to receive FLUTE pkt
    let any = Ipv4Addr::new(0,0,0,0);
    let endpoint = UDPEndpoint::new(None, "224.0.1.201".to_string(), 3400);
    let udp_socket = UdpSocket::bind((any, endpoint.port)).expect("Fail to bind");

    // Create a writer able to write received files to the filesystem
    let writer = match writer::ObjectWriterFSBuilder::new(&std::path::Path::new(r#"C:\Users\myname\Documents\_\Multicast\dest\"#)) {  
        Ok(writer) => Rc::new(writer),  
        Err(err) => {  
            println!("Failed to create object writer: {:?}", err);  
            return;  
        }  
    }; 

    // Create a multi-receiver capable of de-multiplexing several FLUTE sessions
    let mut receiver = MultiReceiver::new(writer, None, false);

    // Receive pkt from UDP/IP socket and push it to the FLUTE receiver
    let mut buf = [0; 2048];
    loop {
        let (n, _src) = udp_socket.recv_from(&mut buf).expect("Failed to receive data");
        let now = SystemTime::now();
        receiver.push(&endpoint, &buf[..n], now).unwrap();
        receiver.cleanup(now);
    }
}

When run in debug mode, I can see it ran through the reciever and sender without exception.
However, udp_socket.recv_from doesn't seem getting anything. And in the end the code stuck in receiver_thread.join().unwrap(); waiting to get content.
I'm very new to all these (UDP, multicast, rust, etc), I think I may mess up multiple parts. But with no exception, I need some clue about what to check with.

There are several adjustments I need but mainly the point is
I need join_multicast_v4 to join multicast IP with regular IP.
Update function like below
fn fn_set_sender() {
    println!("Begin sender");
        // Create UDP Socket
    let udp_socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:0").unwrap();
    //  udp_socket.connect("").expect("Connection failed");
    udp_socket.connect(LOCAL_IP).expect("Connection failed");

    // Create FLUTE Sender
    let tsi = 1;
    let oti = Default::default();
    let config = Default::default();
    let endpoint = UDPEndpoint::new(None, "224.0.1.201".to_string(), 3400);
    let mut sender = Sender::new(endpoint, tsi, &oti, &config);

    // Read all files in the directory into paths  
    if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir("C:/Users/myname/Documents/_/Multicast/src/") {  
        for entry in entries {  
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {  
                let pathBuf = entry.path();  

                let obj = ObjectDesc::create_from_file(
                    pathBuf.as_path(),
                    None,
                    "application/octet-stream",
                    true,
                    1,
                    None,
                    None,
                    None,
                    Cenc::Null,
                    true,
                    None,
                    true,
                )
                .unwrap();
                sender.add_object(0, obj).unwrap(); 
            }  
        }  
    }

    // Always call publish after adding objects
    sender.publish(SystemTime::now());

    // Send FLUTE packets over UDP/IP
    while let Some(pkt) = sender.read(SystemTime::now()) {
        udp_socket.send(&pkt).unwrap();
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(5));
    }
    println!("End sender");
}

fn fn_set_receiver() {

    let endpoint = UDPEndpoint::new(None, "224.0.1.201".to_string(), 3400);
    let any = "0.0.0.0".parse().unwrap();
    let m_cast_group = endpoint.destination_group_address.parse().unwrap();
    // let udp_socket = UdpSocket::bind(("15.38.89.164:3400")).expect("Fail to bind");
    let udp_socket = UdpSocket::bind((any, endpoint.port)).expect("Fail to bind");
    udp_socket.join_multicast_v4(&m_cast_group,&any );

    // Create a writer able to write received files to the filesystem
    let writer = match writer::ObjectWriterFSBuilder::new(&std::path::Path::new(r#"C:\Users\myname\Documents\_\Multicast\dest\"#)) {  
        Ok(writer) => Rc::new(writer),  
        Err(err) => {  
            println!("Failed to create object writer: {:?}", err);  
            return;  
        }   
    }; 

    // Create a multi-receiver capable of de-multiplexing several FLUTE sessions
    let mut receiver = MultiReceiver::new(writer, None, false);

    // Receive pkt from UDP/IP socket and push it to the FLUTE receiver
    let mut buf = [0; 2048];
    loop {
        let (n, _src) = udp_socket.recv_from(&mut buf).expect("Failed to receive data");
        let now = SystemTime::now();
        receiver.push(&endpoint, &buf[..n], now).unwrap();
        receiver.cleanup(now);
    }
}

